# Area under a curve of an odd function from negative infinity to positive infinity

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, even-and-odd-functions

In integration, there is a property that says: If you're integrating from -a to a some odd function f(x), then the area under the curve between -a and a is zero.

I was listening to this in class , and then I thought about integrating some odd function, like x^3, from negative infinity to positive infinity.

But, if you integrate x^3 and then solve it from negative infinity to positive infinity, wouldn't you end up subtracting infinity from infinity, which is undefined?

Given this, which answer is the correct one: is the area 0 or is it undefined?

Comment: It is only zero if the integral is defined. The function $x \mapsto x^3$ is not integrable on the real line, so the integral is **not** defined. You can define an improper integral as the limit, but the integral per so is not defined.

Comment: In general when you have improper integrals you consider the bounds as limits (ie $\int_{0}^{\infty}$ actually represents $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{n}$)(same principle if both bounds are infinite)

Comment: @copper.hat Not sure what you are implying about $x^3$ not being integratable.

Comment: @RushabhMehta: Integrable usually means that the integral is finite.

Comment: @aidangallagher4 that's correct, which is why what TheSimpliFire did is quite incorrect.

Comment: Ah ok, agreed .

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For improper integrals, you're correct: you have to be careful. Both limits need to exist independently of each other. In your case, $\int_{-\infty}^0 x^3\,dx$ is $-\infty$, hence the integral "doesn't exist" (except in the extended real numbers case). There is something called a principal value, where you take the limits simultaneously, e.g., $$\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_{-N}^N x^3\,dx=\lim_{N\to\infty}0=0,$$ and in this sense, the limit will always give $0$.

Answer (score 4):

The improper integral is defined as $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^3dx$=$\lim_{\alpha\to-\infty}\lim_{\beta\to\infty}\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}x^3 dx$, which as you said is undefined as the final calculation is $\infty-\infty$.

However, this integral can be given a value by something called the *Cauchy Principal Value*, which is a method of giving a value to double infinite integrals such as this. It is defined as  $PV\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^3dx$$=\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{-R}^{R}x^3dx$, which will converge to $0$ as your heuristic has you believe.

Comment: There is a small defect in your notation.  You have written that the two limits are taken sequentially.  Correctly, they are taken simultaneously and independently, that is, as $\lim_{(\alpha, \beta) \rightarrow (-\infty, \infty)} \dots$.